# Where does a ResourceBundle get its Locale?

Tags: resources, internationalization, struts, locale, bundle

I'm using resource bundles in a i18n struts application. On most pages the resource bundles select the right language (language is set through i18n struts interceptor). And on one page the resource bundle doesn't select the right language. I can't figure out why. That's why I was wondering where the Locale of the ResourceBundle comes from.

Could calling an action in a frame cause some troubles with the resource bundle ?

Ok so, in a struts action I have the following :

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundleProcess = null;
        try {
            resourceBundleProcess = ResourceBundle
                    .getBundle(BpmUiConstantes.BPMUI_PROCESS_CONF_FOLDER + "/"
                            + caseType);
            LOG.info("Locale used by bundle : " + resourceBundleProcess.getLocale()) ;
        }
```

Through the url I set the locale to "en" for instance by specifying request_locale=en. The i18n struts interceptor is supposed to get the locale and use it. Although, I'm not sure if affects ResourceBundles. I thought it did since on my other pages the text is displayed in the right language. But here the LOG display "fr" for some reason (the browser is in english as well).

Comment: Show us some code. It's not clear if you use the Struts API or the java.util.ResourceBundle API.

Comment: Done, tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResourceBundle.getBundle()`, if you don't pass any locale as argument, uses the default locale of the JVM, as indicated in its [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String%29).

There is no way Struts can have any impact on that.

If you want to use the locale set by the Struts i18n interceptor, either use the Struts API to get your text, as explained in [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/localization.html), or use ActionSupport's `getLocale()` method to get the locale from the session, and pass it to `ResourceBundle.getBundle()`.

Comment: The right language was set with the i18n struts tag. The part using ResourceBundle was not displayed. Which had me mistaken.